# How to control file size in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm writing a dataframe to csv with the following code:

```
df.write\
    .option("header",True) \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("sep","|")\
    .format("csv") \
    .save("filepath")
```

I need to limit the size of the output file to **1gb**.

For example, if the size of the data is **5gb**, the output should be 5 files of **1 gb** each.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can [`repartition()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition.html) the Dataframe before writing. It'll write one file per partition.

Following should produce 5 files.

```py
df2 = df.repartition(5)
df2.write\
    .option("header",True) \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("sep","|")\
    .format("csv") \
    .save("filepath")
```

Comment: This, of course, assumes that you already know what the final size would be. I think the asker wants a way to set a file size limit, and let Spark figure out how many files that needs.

Comment: Yes, Spark should automatically figure out the number of partitions based on the file size limit set.

Comment: @linux I'm not aware of a param that controls size directly. Will check and update if I find something.